# Best way to fill up the gaps in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My data in excel has the following (x,y) pairs (x and y are two columns in excel) (1,4),(2,6),(5,88),(9,67),(12,45) and so on. 
I would like to transform it as following. (1,4),(2,6),(3,0),(4,0),(5,88),(6,0),(7,0),(8,0),(9,67),(10,0),(11,0),(12,45) so on. i.e., I want to insert missing $x$ values with corresponding $y$ values as zeros in data.

Can some one please suggest me a best way to do this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a "complete" array to supplement your manual input array.

#### Manual_Array

```
+----+----+
| x  | y  |
+----+----+
|  1 |  4 |
|  2 |  6 |
|  5 | 88 |
|  9 | 67 |
| 12 | 45 |
+----+----+
```

#### Complete_Array

```
+----+----+
| x  | y  |
+----+----+
|  1 |  4 |
|  2 |  6 |
|  3 |  0 |
|  4 |  0 |
|  5 | 88 |
|  6 |  0 |
|  7 |  0 |
|  8 |  0 |
|  9 | 67 |
| 10 |  0 |
| 11 |  0 |
| 12 | 45 |
+----+----+
```

The `y` column in `Complete_Array` would be a calculated column with a formula of `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@x],Manual_Array,2,0),0)` or similar.

In this way you can still manually assign values as well as manually determine the size of the `x` array.

Comment: To complement this solution use this formula in column `x` of the `Complete_Array` table to fill up the `x` values:
`=IF(D1="X",1, IF(D1=MAX(Manual_Array[x]),CHAR(133), IF(D1=CHAR(133),CHAR(133), SUM(1,D1))))`
The formula assumes the `Complete_Array` table starts at `D1`, enter the formula in `D2` and copy to the last record _(change `D2` as required)_

Comment: @EEM noting, of course that dataTable data ranges have to start in row 2 at min to allow for the `dataTable[#Headers]` ;-)

Comment: @EEM in the example provided, you give `=IF(D1="X"`... as the target. When using a dataTable ( as in my answer - I have not editted to include R1C1 format ); any dataTable using a row 1 reference CANNOT be referencing it's own data range since the row above a dataTable is it's `[#Headers]` range. The MINIMUM row reference given would have to be 2. Both of the arrays I gave were dataTables so   the R1C1 sytnax seems like it may be off.

Comment: When trying to enter a formula and moving the cursor to the header It automatically gives the [[#Headers],[x]] , so it has to be manually written or just copy inside the cell (just did it now as a test and it worked, no need to include R1C1 format).

Comment: you can also write the formula at cell 3 then copy, it does that only for the cell below the header